# How do I make internal method in jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'd like to make internal method in jar file, but I don't know how do I make. For example.

```
public class staff {
    private String Name;
    private String ID;
    private String phone;

    public String getName(){ return Name; }
    public String getId(){ return ID; }
    public String getPhone(){ return phone;}
}
```

Such code is in jar file, but I don't want the user of jar to use "getPhone()" method. I can't change it private because other class in jar refers it.

How do I make it?

Comment: Are the other classes that refer to it in the same package?

Comment: package private perhaps.

Comment: You don't make methods in JAR files. You write methods in Java classes; you compile them; and you package the object files into JAR files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Hovercraft Full Of Eels, your answer is what I'd like to do.
This is my solution.

```
public class staff {
    private String Name;
    private String ID;
    private String phone;

    public String getName(){ return Name; }
    public String getId(){ return ID; }

    //Package-private method!!
    String getPhone(){ return phone;}

}
```

Thank you!!